Supabase - NextJS - User creations issue
Am integrating supabase with NextJS. The integration went smooth. I can create a user, login and logout.
However, from my app and using supabase app I can only create one account. I have to create other users from supabase dashboard.
I am running on NextJS 15 (locally) and Supabase free tier.
I tried checking policies but i don't think it's the issue.
When using the supabase free tier, I am expecting to have multiple app users.

Supabase made a recent change that could be your reason if you are trying to create email logins. From 26th September 2024, if you don’t set up a custom SMTP provider, auth emails will only be sent to members of your project’s organization - aka unless it’s your supabase email, the user won’t be created. Once you use your own smtp setup you can create users not on your account.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
